# Datepicker Calendar button is Taking too much space (WPF)

Tags: wpf

I am using a simple Datepicker control in my View as shown in code below

```
  <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding EndDate}" Margin="3,3,0,3" Grid.Column="3" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" />
```

The date picker control is looking weird as the calendar button is taking half of the space available in datepicker. How shall i make the calendar button small inside the datepicker. 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have have overrode the datepicker style?

Comment: No . This is the only place i use a datepicker